# MASM I can't seem to find the correct element in a C-array to swap

Tags: c++, arrays, masm, bubble-sort

I'm trying my best to learn MASM and today I'm trying to compare bubble sort between C++ and MASM. I've got the C++ working without issue, but when I get into the MASM function, the first element of the array isn't what it should be, usually 3million something instead of the random value between 0-32767. Then the values of the registers I am comparing will not swap and read the same random, unsorted array I passed into the function. I also find that I can't iterate through the array. Thanks!

c++ code (not that important)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int deepBlueDecend(int* num, int size);
int deepBlueAscend(int* num, int size);
//int setArray(int* num, int size);

extern"C"
{
    int KasparovAscend(int *, int);
    int KasparovDecend(int *, int);
}

int main()
{
    int ascOrDec = 2, size = 0;
    cout << "How big do you want the array to be sorted? ";
    cin >> size;

    int* myArray = 0;
    myArray = new int[size];
    int* asmArray = 0;
    asmArray = new int[size];

    srand((unsigned)time(0));                       // gets actually random numbers somehow
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)                  //populates the arrays with random numbers
    {
        myArray[i] = rand();
        asmArray[i] = myArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << asmArray[i] << " "; //displays asmArray[]
    cout << endl;

    while (ascOrDec < 0 || ascOrDec > 1)            //test if ascending or decending has been chosen
    {
        cout << "Ascending (0) or decending(1)? ";
        cin >> ascOrDec;        
        if (ascOrDec == 0 || ascOrDec == 1)
            break;
    }

    cout << endl;
    if (ascOrDec == 0)
    {
        KasparovAscend(myArray, size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << asmArray[i] << " "; //to see if anything changed in the assembly sort
        cout << endl;

        clock_t startTime = clock();
        deepBlueAscend(myArray, size);
        clock_t endTime = clock();
        clock_t clockTicksTaken = endTime - startTime;
        double timeInSeconds = clockTicksTaken / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << myArray[i] << " "; //to see if anything changed in the C++ sort
        cout << "\nTime Taken for c++: " << clockTicksTaken << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        clock_t startTime = clock();
        deepBlueDecend(myArray, size);
        clock_t endTime = clock();
        clock_t clockTicksTaken = endTime - startTime;
        double timeInSeconds = clockTicksTaken / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "\nTime Taken for c++: " << clockTicksTaken << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int deepBlueAscend(int* arr, int size)
{
    int i, j, flag = 1;    // set flag to 1 to start first pass
    int temp;             // holding variable

    for (i = 1; (i <= size) && flag; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < (size - 1); j++)
        {
            if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])      // ascending order <
            {
                temp = arr[j];             // swap elements
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = 1;               // indicates that a swap occurred.
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int deepBlueDecend(int* arr, int size)
{
    int i, j, flag = 1;    // set flag to 1 to start first pass
    int temp;             // holding variable

    for (i = 1; (i <= size) && flag == 1; i++)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < (size - 1); j++)
        {
            if (arr[j + 1] > arr[j])      // decending order  >
            {
                temp = arr[j];             // swap elements
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = 1;               // indicates that a swap occurred.
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Masm Code:

```
.686
.model flat
.code

_KasparovAscend PROC ; named _test because C automatically prepends an underscode, it is needed to interoperate
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp ; stack pointer to ebp

    push edi            ;save this
    push ebx            ;save this

    mov ebx,[ebp+8]     ; address of first array element
    mov ecx,[ebp+12]    ; number of elements in array

    mov edi, [ebx+4]        ;second element
    mov edx, 0          ;set counter to 0




LoopTraverse:
    cmp ecx, edx
    je AllDone
    inc edx                 ;increment loopTraverse counter
    mov eax, -1             ;set couter in loopSwap to be 0 when first entered


    LoopSwap:
        inc eax             ;increment
        cmp ecx, eax        ;compares counter to number of elements
        je LoopTraverse     
        cmp edi, ebx        ;comparing the two values
        jg NextElements

        push ebx            ;trade the two elements
        mov ebx, edi
        pop edi

        add ebx, 4          ;goes to the next element in array
        add edi, 4
        jmp LoopSwap

        NextElements:
            add ebx, 4      ;goes to next element in array
            add edi, 4
            jmp LoopSwap

allDone:

    pop edi
    pop edx
    pop ebp
    ret
_KasparovAscend ENDP

END
```

Comment: You're missing a bit of indirection in the assembly code.

Comment: After 15 minutes, I can't seem to figure out what you mean. Could you please be a little more specific? Thanks.

Comment: The code at "trade the two elements" exhanges the values of registers `ebx` and `edi` (in a needlessly roundabout way, but anyway). The first time this happens, `ebx` holds a pointer to the first item, while `edi` holds the value of the second item. So it's a bit of nonsense going on right there. The following code indicates that you intend for these two register to hold pointers or indices. So presumably what's lacking is (1) a bit of indirection, following the pointers, so to speak, and (2) proper initialization so both registers contain the same kind of value, e.g. pointer.

Comment: So, what I should do is compare values, right? Then, how do I find the value of the first element? I've looked at numerous websites and can't find anything like that.

If I should compare addresses, how do I make edi go to an address?

Comment: In your current code the instruction `mov edi, [ebx+4]` uses `ebx` as a pointer, to fetch an array item value from memory to register `edi`. Corresponding in C or C++ would be `edi = *(ebx + 4)` or `edi = ebx[4]` (they do the same *by definition*). Well except that the C++ code would only fetch a single byte. It would probably be a good idea to use a tutorial or book about x86 assembly programming. You also need an instruction set quick reference.